# Pandas pct_change on only one column in the data frame to create a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, methods

I'm attempting to add a new column in my pandas data frame for the daily % change of a specific column in my dataframe. Whenever I try to use the pct_change() method, it creates a new dataframe and applies pct_change() to all columns in the df. Below is the table I currently have:

|  | new_date | Name | sentiment_polarity | sentiment_score | engagement | engagement_polarity_score | engagement_sentiment_score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2020-01-01 | Bitcoin | 0.342000 | 0.107069 | 6.142000 | -0.325000 | 0.589380 |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | Cardano | 0.334572 | 0.133310 | 11.256506 | 8.866171 | 2.509937 |
| 2 | 2020-01-01 | Dogecoin | 0.434783 | 0.155303 | 13.173913 | 11.121739 | 2.742231 |
| 3 | 2020-01-01 | Ethereum | 0.389000 | 0.133417 | 6.121000 | 4.652000 | 1.480854 |
| 4 | 2020-01-01 | Stellar | 0.759000 | 0.216281 | 7.437000 | 6.385000 | 1.851542 |
| 5 | 2020-01-02 | Bitcoin | 0.202000 | 0.067189 | 4.512000 | 1.536000 | 0.568809 |
| 6 | 2020-01-02 | Cardano | 0.307971 | 0.120505 | 17.282609 | 5.355072 | 1.606946 |
| 7 | 2020-01-02 | Dogecoin | 0.266667 | 0.095962 | 2.266667 | 1.276190 | 0.553433 |
| 8 | 2020-01-02 | Ethereum | 0.244000 | 0.098055 | 9.670000 | 4.583000 | 1.637720 |
| 9 | 2020-01-02 | Stellar | 0.729000 | 0.206842 | 5.765000 | 4.617000 | 1.093504 |

I'd like for there to be another column at the end that captures the daily % change of the engagement_sentiment_score column.

I tried using the below snippet but get an error:

```
Bit['Daily % Sentiment Change'] = Bit.pct_change(axis=1)['engagement_sentiment_score']
```

Error message: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'

I then checked the data type for the values in the engagement_sentiment_score column and it says that they are floats, so I'm unsure why I'm getting this error.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `select_dtypes()` to select only int and float values:

```
Bit['Daily % Sentiment Change'] =(Bit.select_dtypes(include=['int','float'])
                                     .pct_change(axis=1)['engagement_sentiment_score'])
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I no longer get the error, but it looks like the calculation is not what I would've anticipated. The new column is not calculating the daily % change when I try to sanity check it.

Comment: @J.Smith so try`Bit['engagement_sentiment_score'].pct_change()`

Comment: Got it! Thanks, Anurag, much apprecaited